# Subset dataset based on crosstalk value in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, crosstalk

I use crosstalk in order to be able to click on a bar in the barplot and subset the table below based on the `Abcd`. For some reason if I press on a bar I get only one row of the dataset while I should get all of them. If I select all the bars again the table still displayes only one row.

````
---
title: "Operaitonal dashboard"
author: "Report"
date: 'Date: `r Sys.Date()`'
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    theme: lumen
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}


knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE,
                      warning= FALSE,
                      message = FALSE)
library(crosstalk)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)
##The four dataframes

Abcd<-c("A","A","B","B")
Prod<-c(34,56,56,89)
Div<-c("Ent","Ent","App","High")
dcross1<-data.frame(Abcd,Prod,Div)


Counts<-c(45,67,78,56)
dcross2<-data.frame(Div,Abcd,Counts)


shared_df <- SharedData$new(dcross1, key = ~Abcd, group = "group")
shared_df2 <- SharedData$new(dcross2, key = ~Abcd, group = "group")


```

# Out of stock Report {data-icon="fa-cart-arrow-down" data-orientation=rows}

## Row {data-height="200"}

### Out Of Stock: Store Overview {data-width="200"}

```{r Oos Store}
daily_store_oos_gg<-
  ggplot(shared_df,
         aes(x=Abcd,
             y=Prod,
             fill=as.factor(Abcd)
             )) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") 

# Convert to plotly object
daily_store_oos_ply <- 
  ggplotly(daily_store_oos_gg)

daily_store_oos_ply
```

## Column {data-width=405}


### Store Overview Out of Stock
```{r out of stock reactable}
daily_item_oos_rctble<-reactable(
    shared_df2
    )

daily_item_oos_rctble

```
````

Comment: Perhaps you should check if the merges are working to your expectation.  There is no record of Counts=34 from supplier data frame in total3, and there are 6 records.

Comment: The goal of my merge is to simply merge everything based on Abcd which is the common variable of all dataframes. Why does this not work?

Comment: I updated with non-merged dfs and still does not work

Comment: `crosstalk` and the function `reactable` don't seem compatible. Substituting `reactable` with `DT::datatable` worked for me. Have a look at https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/widgets.html for compatible packages with `crosstalk`

Comment: that is super useful info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by someone, `reactable` does not work well with `crosstalk`. Perhaps your data could be prepared as shown below.

Try this

```
Abcd<-c("A","A","B","B")
Prod<-c(34,56,56,89)
Div<-c("Ent","Ent","App","High")
dcross1<-data.frame(Abcd,Prod,Div)

Countd<-c(45,67,78,56)
dcross2<-data.frame(Div,Abcd,Countd)

Store<-c(199,199)
Abcd<-c("A","B")
Oos<-c(500,400)
store<-data.frame(Store,Abcd,Oos, flag=1)

Man<-c("Corp","Adv","Corp","Adv")
Abcd<-c("A","B","A","B")
Counts<-c(45,56,34,78)
Scounts<-c(23,45,67,67)
Per<-c(1,2,3,5)
supplier<-data.frame(Abcd,Man,Counts,Scounts,Per) # %>% SharedData$new() 
supplier2 <- supplier[order(supplier$Abcd),]

dcross <- cbind(dcross1[,2:3], dcross2[,2:3], supplier2[,2:5]) %>% mutate(id = row_number())

dcross_sub <- group_by(dcross, Abcd) %>% slice(1) %>% select(Abcd, id)
store_sub <- merge(x = dcross_sub, y = store, by = "Abcd", all = TRUE)

dcrossf <- merge(x = dcross, y = store_sub[,2:5], by = "id", all = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  bscols(widths = 6,
         list(
           plotlyOutput("storep"),
           DTOutput("dcross1t")
         )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  row.names(dcrossf) <- NULL
  
  dcross11 <- SharedData$new(dcrossf, key = ~Abcd, group = "group")
  store2 <- SharedData$new(subset(dcrossf, flag==1), key = ~Abcd, group = "group")

  daily_store_oos_gg<-
    ggplot(store2,
           aes(x=Abcd,
               y=Oos,
               fill=as.factor(Abcd)
           )) + labs(fill="Abcd") +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")

  # Convert to plotly object
  daily_store_oos_ply <-
    ggplotly(daily_store_oos_gg)

  output$storep <- renderPlotly({daily_store_oos_gg })

  output$dcross1t <- renderDT({dcross11}, server=FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: maybe you could help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564769/create-interaction-between-charts-and-tables-using-javascript-in-a-flexdashboard. This can be achieved in a shiny envrinoment as well.